# Swift UIViewController inheritance issue

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a Page View controller to control page navigation. The page itself is a UViewController called **BookPageViewController**. There is no problem to assign a property ***vc.myproperty*** inside this **BookPageViewController** until I inherit this page from a **BasePageViewController** which is a UIViewController. The app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x10). I then move the variable from **BookPageViewController** to **BasePageViewController**, then app works again.

Here is my code:

```
 // BookPageViewController
 class BookPageViewController: BasePageViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var myproperty : Property!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

 // BasePageViewController: do nothing
 class BasePageViewController: UIViewController {

 }

 // my code to get the BookPageViewController
func viewControllerAtIndex(index : Int) -> BookPageViewController? {

    if self.mydata.count == 0 || index >= self.mydata.count {
        return nil
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    let vc = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyBookPageViewController") as BookPageViewController
    vc.myproperty = thepropertyData

    return vc
}
```

I'm sure the *thepropertyData* has a value.

Can anybody help to explain what happened here? Thanks

Comment: Which version of Xcode, beta3 or beta4?

Answer (score 0):

Do a Clean on the project, there is a bug causing weird bad access. I had it in beta 3

Comment: Really? I tried to "Clean" and even deleted the derived data and rebuild. Still the same problem.

Comment: Try making a new project and add back all the files... A bit of work, but some people say that helped them. Also try upgrading to beta 4.